# Problems with Steam

Tags: steam

I am having troubles with my SteamCMD. I cannot get the Steam CMD start code to work and I cannot get Garry's Mod to open on it either.

I have tried things such as

```
touch $HOME/.steam/steam/steam_install_agreement.txt
```

and

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
mv .steam/SteamApps ~/Downloads/
rm -rf .steam* .local/share/Steam
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

Errors: http://pastebin.com/ghrcAzUp

Answer (score 0):

A large portion of Steam games isn't available in Ubuntu because most games are built platform dependently.

However, you can use install Steam virtually using [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/). This way you can use steam like you were using it on Windows.

Installation instructions: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#With_Play_On_Linux_.28POL.29

Comment: I meant like running a dedicated server. SteamCMD runs a new version of SRCDS. I cannot get that to work correctly.